# how do i pass label text to another page via session array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session, post

Need help to passing label text to another page via session array and also i have tried to post radio button values but problem is that radio button values didn't display into another page?

**Index Page Php Function**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST['demo'])) {
    $_SESSION['size'] = array('Small', 'Medium');
}
?>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.form-radios label').attr('checked', 'unchecked');
$(".form-radios label").click(function(){
$(this).attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked');
$('label').not(this).removeClass('checked');
});  
});

</script>
```

**Index Page Form**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-radios">

        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size" value="Small" />
        <label for="size">Small</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size" value="medium"/>
        <label for="size">Medium</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size" value="large"/>
        <label for="size">Large</label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" id="size" value="xl"/>
        <label for="size">Xl</label>

    </div><br />
    <input type="submit" name="demo" value="submit" />

</form>
```

**Page2 Function**

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $sizes=$_SESSION['size'];
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo  $sizes ?>" />
```

Comment: You can use `var_dump` to test the values like `var_dump($_SESSION)` and `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to make sure everything is what you expected

Answer (score 1):

Your session is an array you have to loop it.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['sizes'] as $size)
{
    echo $size;
}
```

Comment: in `page2.php` right? but i want to `post radio values`  how could i send?

Comment: Can you elaborate question. It will be easy to answer.

Comment: chandresh i want to send radio values to another page via any method whether it will be session or javascript or jquery?

Comment: Why do u need session, you can use form submit to post radio values right?

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to post radio values how could I send?

Radio values from your form are sent automatically to the action specified when a user press the submit button. In the action page they can retrieve them via the `$_POST` or `$_GET` global array. In your case, since you are using the POST method, you can retrieve your radio box via:

```
$_POST['size'];
```

---

> Actually I want to send when someone click on label then label values to another page.

Well, you can do that by make Javascript trigger an event when a radio box is selected and send a request via AJAX.

Comment: actually i want to send when someone click on label then label values to another page